# iOS16 ShareLink URLScheme Rich Link Preview SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16, swiftui-sharelink

I would like to have a button in the app that popups a ShareSheet with a link that routes to my app, via the ShareLink API. [From this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2444/_index.html), iOS and macOS will automatically generate inline previews for links people send.

However, if creating a link to the app itself (using a URL Type/Scheme), how can I get the fancy preview to work? I added an icon to my URL scheme but it doesn't seem to do anything.

I am using the SwiftUI and the ShareLink API.

I tried:

1. ShareLink
2. LinkPresentation
3. URL Scheme

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.